# Using telegraf with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, telegraf

```
[inputs.kafka_consumer] Error in plugin: consume: dial tcp: lookup cd191218e4d8 on 192.168.0.1:53: no such host.
```

The docker logs of telegraf print this error, Maybe the error caused by DNS? telegraf and kafka container don't in the same net, the actually ip of inputs.kafka_consumer is 192.168.0.xx:9092

Answer (score 0):

> telegraf and kafka container don't in the same net

They need to be. Kafka's `advertised.listeners` setting must be resolvable by the Telegraf client.

The `cd191218e4d8` appears to be a Docker container hostname, which is unresolvable without being on the same network.

You shouldn't use your LAN IP between two containers on the same Docker bridge network.